# Pass as onChange parameter all the HTML content of a div in React for a useState

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to be able to save the entire content of the div. As the "element" parameter, you can enter any HTML content. If there is a change to that HTML, it is simply updated by saving it with its useStat.
In the line , how could I pass the HTML content of the "div" tag itself as a parameter?

```
const ElementoPaginacion = ({element}) =>{
    const [content, saveElement] = useState(element);

    const saveData = (newData) =>{
        saveElement(newData);
    }
    return(
        <div onChange={saveData}>
            {element}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This currently sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you explain in some more detail (edit your question) the problem that you're trying to solve with this code? It might be all you need is a wrapper container into which is passed `children` (which would be a set of JSX) but at this point it's difficult to tell.

Comment: The idea is to have a component (ElementoPaginacion) capable of modifying all the HTML that is passed to it as a parameter. I have not included all the code because it is very long and I sense that it would only make it difficult to solve the problem.
The idea is to have a data paging component. This data may contain elements (chebox, radiobuttons) that can be modified. It is not known a priori what data can be passed to the paging component, so it would simply have to be able to modify any HTML passed.